# Replacing character in an array element

Tags: java

I have a string array storing the following elments two elements having
`startdatetime`, `enddatetime` and retry seperated by `-`

> 20160504 14:30:40-20160504 22:02:05-3, 20160504 14:30:40-20160504 22:02:05-3

I want to reduce the the retry count by 1 and again wanted to store the same value into another array or same.

So the o/p should be like this

> 20160504 14:30:40-20160504 22:02:05-2, 20160504 14:30:40-20160504 22:02:05-2

Comment: Hmm... This is very convoluted? Can you rephrase your question? to replace a character you just assign it to something else or null a[1] = null; a1[0] = " "

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried?

Comment: Don't manipulate strings. Manipulate structured data structures, i.e. Objects. You should have a list of instances of `Attempt`, where `Attempt` is a class with a start time, an end time, and a retryCount.

Comment: Amazing. Just two days ago this very question was downvoted to -7 and closed, now it has been upvoted and answered (kind of). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921992/splitting-the-elements-of-an-array?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating String that is structured in this way will cause problems in the future, plus its a bad coding to store Dates and other elements with a separator in a string array, I would suggest to do it this way:

**First create a class for your elements and lets call it Elements**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

public class Elements {
private int retryCount;
private LocalDateTime startDate;
private LocalDateTime endDate;

public Elements(int retryCount, LocalDateTime startDate, LocalDateTime endDate) {
    super();
    this.retryCount = retryCount;
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.endDate = endDate;
}
public int getRetryCount() {
    return retryCount;
}
public void setRetryCount(int retryCount) {
    this.retryCount = retryCount;
}
public LocalDateTime getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}
public void setStartDate(LocalDateTime startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}
public LocalDateTime getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}
public void setEndDate(LocalDateTime endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}

}
```

then store whatever objects you have in a List of Elements For Example:

```
List<Elements> elements=new ArrayList<Elements>();
elements.add(yourObj);
```

Then use a for-each to access your object properties, in this way you can easily manipulate your objects.